# How to use Rails (outside docker) with Postgres (inside docker)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I hope to launch all dependent services (e.g. Postgres) in docker but my Rails app outside alone.

Is there any practice for this? How to configure Rails?

BTW, I have mapped port from `5432` in docker to `5111` (which means Postgres `11.1`) on host:

```
# docker-compose.yml
image: postgres:11.1
ports:
  - "5111:5432"
environment:
  - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=testpass
  - POSTGRES_USER=testuser
volumes:
  - ${HOME}/.tmp/pg-11.1:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can check if you indeed have access to postgres container:

```
$ psql -p 5111 -U testuser -h localhost
```

If your postgres container is available on port 5111 from the rails app environment, then you need the following inside `config/database.yml`:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: testuser
  password: testpass
  port: 5111
```